# what's the maximum number of requests with oauth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api, google-oauth

How many requests can you do with 1 oauth2 account combined with the google analytics API ?
And if you reach the max. is it possible to get more requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit for the Google Analytics API is 50,000 API request per day.  The query limit is 1 request/second/user.  You can find more of this information and request more quota via Google APIs Console code.google.com/apis/console

Answer (score 0):

All of the information you're looking for is available on the Google Analytics Developer site:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/limits-quotas